# hidden input not set with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to set hidden vaulue and it turned out all NULL. But when I debugged it, they are getting the right values.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var name="campaign";   
   var url=document.URL;
    var campaign= decodeURI(
     (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]);
name="source";
var source=decodeURI(
    (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]);
name="medium";
var medium=decodeURI(
    (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]);
   $('#campaign').val(campaign);
   $('#source').val(source);
   $('#medium').val(medium);
 }); 


</script>

<input type="hidden" id="campaign" name="campaign" value="null">
<input type="hidden" id="medium" name="medium" value="null">
<input type="hidden" id="source" name="source" value="null">
```

Comment: what do you mean of `But when I debugged it, they are getting the right values.` means no problem?

Comment: getting value from url has no problem, just setting value has problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your HTML code value="null" sets value to string "null", not JavaScript null value
2. I would function from [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) to get parameter values from URL.